# for each loop of objects of specific instances in Java

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

I'd like to have a for each loop to loop through an array of objects.. but only the objects that are an instance of a specific class. To be more clear of what I mean, I've included the example below...

```
//Declare a list of employee objects
List<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<Employees>;

//Create some employees...
Employee employee = new Employee();
//The class EmployeeExtender extends and is a child of Employee 
EmployeeExtender employeeExtended = new EmployeeExtender(); 

//Now add all the employees, even the ones of different instances to the list
employees.add(employee);
employees.add(employeeExtended);
```

Now I would like to introduce a for each loop that loops through the `employees` list that only loops through employees that are an instance of `EmployeeExtender`. I could just loop through each one and use an if statement (as shown below) but I would like to know if there was a way without making a seperate list to do this.

```
//I would like to only loop through employees that are an instance of EmployeeExtender
for(Employee employee : employees){
    //I would like to not have this if statement...
    if(employee instanceof EmployeeExtender){
        //do logic...
    }
}
```

Are my only options creating separate lists, or using the if statement? I'd like to know if there are more options. Thanks.

Comment: You can do something equivalent using streams, but it's the worst of the three options.

Comment: One way or another if they're all in the same list then you need to iterate over each object in the list. You could filter using any of a number of mechanisms to make it *seem* like you're only hitting the ones you want, e.g., https://zeroturnaround.com/rebellabs/java-8-explained-applying-lambdas-to-java-collections/, but you have a single list, and without interrogating each item, how would you know what it is?

Comment: You could do something like `employees.stream().filter(e -> e instanceOf ExmployeeExtender).forEach( . . . )` ; well, unless you use a custom list which provides a iterator only on the objects that are instances of EmployeeExtender, but that's really just moving your filtering around.

Comment: Really the simplest solution is the one you already have and I'm not sure why you wouldn't just go with that. Another option however is to implement your own list with an iterator that skips what you want.

Comment: `foreach ( Employee employee : filter(employees) )` is the one liner, but would require you to implement `filter` to do exactly what you are already doing in your example. It is therefore rather redundant, and in many cases less readable.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem, why is it the worst of the three options?

Comment: In simple words, if you put apples, oranges and **fruits** in the basket of fruits, and you want to do something *only* with apples, you'll have to pick one by one item from your basket and **see** if is it an apple or not... IMHO, either you should reconsider your data structure (e.g implementing map), or use the streams (better option than yours), or use your own code.

Comment: I don't know if this is compatible with your logic, but you could write a function in Employee which does nothing and overwrite it in EmplyoyeeExtender with the function doing the logic. And in the loop call always this function.

Comment: @zlakad _'or use the streams (better option than yours)'_ contradicts another comment. Why is it that a stream would be better if I'm to look through each **fruit** anyway?

Comment: B/c the streams are implemented in the way to exploit maximum performance (like laziness, extremely optimized internal loops, parallelism etc...).

Comment: There is real, measurable overhead in creating a stream.  Here, there is no purpose in using the stream, so the overhead is for nothing.  Not only is you original code (with the for-each loop around the `instanceof` check) more readable, it will perform better.  Note that if you're checking for more than one subtype, it would be worthwhile using dispatching and polymorphism.

Comment: The accepted answer and your code are logically equivalent. To do some performance (benchmark) tests, you should "warm up" the JVM... There are some excellent discussions about this topic. Also, I'd suggest using `employees.parallelStream()` or `employees.stream().parallel` if you don't care would be data processed in sequential order.

Comment: About readability, this is a matter of opinion - maybe @DawoodibnKareem is used to read `if` statements more efficiently than `filter`? IDK, my view is different...

Comment: OK, about readability, as @zlakad points out, it's certainly a matter of opinion.  About performance, it really isn't.  Loads of people have done loads of studies on this.  Unless you're dealing with millions of objects in your stream, using the stream is a completely unnecessary overhead, that degrades performance instead of improving it.  Don't do it unless you're sure you need to.  But don't take my word for it, or zlakad's.  Do your own research.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem, fair enough - I agree!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Streams:

```
employees.stream()
    .filter(employee -> employee instanceof EmployeeExtender)
    .forEach(employee -> {
        //do logic
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

One option that hasn't been considered is to dispatch the logic to an empty method, that's overridden in the subclass you're interested in.  I don't think I'd recommend doing it this way, but you did ask for options other than the straightforward for-each / instanceof way of doing it.

```
public class Employee {
    public void doTheLogic(TheClassYoureCallingFrom caller) {
    }
}

public class EmployeeExtended extends Employee {
    @Override
    public void doTheLogic(TheClassYoureCallingFrom caller) {
        // The actual logic goes here.
    }
}

public class TheClassYoureCallingFrom {

    List<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<Employees>;

    public void theMethodYoureCallingFrom() {
        for (Employee employee : employees) {
            employee.doTheLogic(this);
        }
    }
}
```

Of course, if you're not using any of the methods of the calling class, there's no need to pass it as a parameter.